# Simplify this rational ${f(x)\over g(x)}$ expression if it is possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$${1-x^8\over x^{12}-10x^{10}+37x^8-42x^6+26x^4-8x^2+1}$$

I have tried and can't simplify this expression any further. 
**Can anyone please help me if you can, to simplify this above rational expression?**

The denominator, I can't see what are the factors

$y=x^2$

$${1-y^4\over y^{6}-10y^{5}+37y^4-42y^3+26y^2-8y+1}$$

Comment: Is this the original expression that you were asked to simplify?  Or is it the result of previous steps?  If the latter, have you verified that the previous steps are correct?  If the former, what have you tried so far?  The numerator can be factored as a difference of squares.  The denominator factors, but it is not obvious to me how to factor it by hand (i.e. without a CAS).

Comment: this is the original expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given expression, as per substitution, gives
$$G(y)=\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}={1-y^4\over y^{6}-10y^{5}+37y^4-42y^3+26y^2-8y+1}$$
$$={(1-y^2)(1+y^2)\over y^{6}-10y^{5}+37y^4-42y^3+26y^2-8y+1}$$
$$={(1-y)(1+y)(y+i)(y-i)\over y^{6}-10y^{5}+37y^4-42y^3+26y^2-8y+1}$$

Now, $G(1)=G(-1)=\frac{0}{5}=0$

And $G(i)=G(-i)=\frac{0}{11+24i}=0$

This implies, that the denominator and the numerator do not have any common roots, i.e. common factors.

Hence, the given expression is irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left(   x^{12}  - 10 x^{10}  + 37 x^{8}  - 42 x^{6}  + 26 x^{4}  - 8 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 5682 x^{6}  - 3843 x^{4}  - 2682 x^{2}  - 5218 }{ 87125 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{8}  - 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 5682 x^{10}  + 52977 x^{8}  - 174486 x^{6}  + 118055 x^{4}  - 39062 x^{2}  - 81907 }{ 87125 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

...................

Answer (score 0):

Here's a session with Pari-GP:

```
> gp
                      GP/PARI CALCULATOR Version 2.9.3 (released)
              i386 running darwin (x86-64/GMP-6.1.2 kernel) 64-bit version
            compiled: Jul 15 2017, Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
                                threading engine: single
                     (readline v7.0 enabled, extended help enabled)

                         Copyright (C) 2000-2017 The PARI Group

PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT 
ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?15 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 8000000, primelimit = 500000
? ?gcd
gcd(x,{y}): greatest common divisor of x and y.
? ?gcdext
gcdext(x,y): returns [u,v,d] such that d=gcd(x,y) and u*x+v*y=d.

? f=x^{12}-10*x^{10}+37*x^8-42*x^6+26*x^4-8*x^2+1
%1 = x^12 - 10*x^10 + 37*x^8 - 42*x^6 + 26*x^4 - 8*x^2 + 1
? g=x^8-1
%2 = x^8 - 1
? gcd(f,g)
%3 = 1
? gcdext(f,g)
%4 = [5682/87125*x^6 + 3843/87125*x^4 + 2682/87125*x^2 + 5218/87125, -5682/87125*x^10 + 52977/87125*x^8 - 174486/87125*x^6 + 23611/17425*x^4 - 39062/87125*x^2 - 81907/87125, 1]
? quit
Goodbye!
```

The two polynomials are coprime.

Comment: I see, pari puts individual coefficients in lowest terms. I wrote my thing to put all on a common denominator. Nice to see confirmation.

Comment: @WillJagy I trust more Pari-GP than my computations by hand. :-)

Comment: Right. But this is my own  C++ program (with GMP for large integers), that  puts directly into typeset Latex. Took me some time...